# Can you query the DB inside a validate_doc_update function?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am using validate_doc_update functions to do basic validation on the object to be stored. This is great to ensure that certain fields are present for example. But is there a way to do a validation based on a query from within the validate_doc_update function? For example, I want people to be able to sign up to bring items to a potluck. So each object will have fields for name, phone, and food (e.g. soda, salad, chips). So my validation function will check for each of those fields. No problem. But I also want to make sure that no more than two people sign up for the same food (not just a basic unique constraint). So if a new object with food value "chips" is being validated, and there are already 2 objects with food value "chips" in the DB, the validation should fail. Is there a way to do this with validation docs?

Answer (score 1):

There is no facility to run a query in validate_doc_update.

One way to solve this issue is to decouple food items from user documents; instead have a document that represents the potluck:

```
{
   _id: "potluck",
   chips: { 
      needed: 2,
      providers: ["user_id_1"]
   },
   soda: {
     needed: 5,
     providers: ["user_id_2","user_id_3"]
   }
}
```

Here it is quite easy to validate sign ups of items. This document exudes a lot of information e.g. the number of items needed for any item is always `needed - providers.length`.  User id's link food items users have signed up to provide.

It would be easy to generate a potluck report using a view or two with this approach.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, though if the needed number is dynamic then it is hard to maintain. What I'm looking at now is a custom plug-in that modifies bulkDocs to do the validation there.

Comment: This may provide some inspiration https://github.com/pouchdb-community/transform-pouch

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It turns out transform-pouch is exactly what I needed! Inside graph.transform in the incoming function, I have access to the db object and I can run any query I want and return the doc as a promise.

Comment: I will add: beware of concurrency pitfalls. For example it is possible with client side validation two users could get the thumbs up to proceed.  Validating the potluck document change should ensure there would be only 1 winner.  It really depends on the workflow which you know and I do not.

Comment: Good point...probably not a big deal in this POC application, but if it were something mission-critical I'd have to deal with concurrency.